# Debug-logging without using Serial.print and without WiFi

Tags: serial, hc-05, debugging

In order to transmit text from the Arduino board to the HC-05 Bluetooth module, I have use `Serial.print`. However, I don't see a way to debug the code without using `Serial.print` to test the other features of the software. Is there another way to transmit text from the Arduino to the computer, and from the Arduino to the HC-05, simultaneously (and without WiFi)?

Comment: Yes. Plenty. You could add WiFi to it. You could use an external UART adaptor and SoftwareSerial. You could add Ethernet to it. There's many ways.

Comment: WiFi isn't available in this case. I'll edit the question.

Comment: The simplest is probably to just use SoftwareSerial and an external USB to UART adaptor. Or just move the HC-05 to other pins and use SoftwareSerial with it (as long as you're no faster than around 9600 baud).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what version of Arduino are you using?

- For **Arduino Mega**, you can use `Serial.println` for writing debug data and `Serial1.println` for communication with HC-05. (See Example: [MultiSerial Example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MultiSerialMega))
- For **other Arduino boards**, you can use `Serial.println` for writing debug data and SoftwareSerial library for communication with HC-05. (See Example: [SofwareSerial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SoftwareSerialExample))

Comment: I'm using an Arduino Uno.

Comment: Ok, connect RXD pin and TXD pin of HC-05 to pin 10 and 11 of Arduino Uno and follow SoftwareSerial example. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SoftwareSerialExample